# Django/Nodejs - upload large chunked files

Tags: python, node.js, django

i have a node server and a django server. I try to send large file from the node to the django server.

I send the large file from node server by using fs.createReadStream() function. Each chunk created is send to the django server.

I'am new in Django, so i don't know how to handle chunks. I tried to look the doc, but nothing seems clear for me.

I need to store entire file in MEDIA_ROOT path.

```
var output = fs.createWriteStream("../tmp_upload/" + pathname.split('/')[0] + ".zip");
        archive.pipe(output);
        archive
        .directory('../tmp_upload/' + pathname.split('/')[0])
        .finalize();
        output.on('close', function(){
            const stats = fs.statSync("../tmp_upload/" + pathname.split('/')[0] + ".zip")
            const fileSizeInBytes = stats.size
            let content = fs.createReadStream("../tmp_upload/" + pathname.split('/')[0] + ".zip")
            var chunk_sum = 0
            var index = 0
            content.on('data', chunk => {
                chunk_sum += chunk.length
                const data = {
                    token: req.session.userToken,

                    patientfile: {
                        file: chunk.toString(),
                        sumOfChunks: chunk_sum,
                        fileSize: fileSizeInBytes,
                        index : index,
                        label: pathname.split('/')[0] + ".zip",
                        category: "OT",


                    }



            };
            index += 1

            Store.patientFileAdd(data) // here is where i send the chunk to django 


            });
```

here is a part of my nodejs function

class PatientFileAdd(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:

        filedata = request.data['patientfile']
        file = filedata['file']
        file_start = filedata['index']


        upload_folder = "/patient/patient_%s" % request.userprofile.patientaccount, filedata['label']
        with open(upload_folder, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)



        return toolsViews.ResponseHandler(
                status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED,
                {
                    'patientfile': 'OK'
                }
            )
```

Here my Django view

Thanks